# Dynamic cell Size for TextView & ImageView in same cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` and I need Dynamic cell size for both depending if the `textView` has more text inside of it.

I am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

[image]
[image]

**UI Example:**

The `cell` is expanding with the text amount but is not expanding the `UIImage`. What am I doing wrong? How should I add the constraints to adapt to this situation? Let me know if you need more information.

[image]

The image is going beneath the fixed cell size in the `storyBoard`.

If I add a bottom constraint where the red circle is in the second image the textView text is only on one line and is no longer dynamic.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

if I add bottom to superView textView no longer dynamic.
(Compare to image above.)

The bottom constraint is my main issue when trying to make them work together.

[image]

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: Provide bottomSpaceToSuperview for your UIImageview

Comment: please show your table estimated height and height forrow method

Comment: It is difficult to make dynamic `textView` because it has scrollable property inside `textView`. So better option is to take `UILabel`

Comment: I need it to be a textView for links and other purposes. i Turned scrolling off

Comment: I have added updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using Auto layout, there is a simpler way to do this without any calculating stuff, so you can also forget away `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate, just let Auto layout do its job.

Well, the essential of the trick are just three things:

Set needed auto layout params on cell content.

1. Enable UITableViewAutomaticDimension on tableview cell height.
2. Give some pre-estimation number for tableview (for optimizing scrolling speed).
3. Set needed auto layout params on cell content

Just remember the rule is all items on table view cell need to be pinned on `top, bottom,leadingand trailing` edges from parent view. For example if your table view cell have two labels: `brandNameLabel & brandAddressLabel`, so the layout for those label would be:

**For brandNameLabel:**

[image]

**For brandAddressLabel:**

[image]

For more you should see this [REFERENCE](https://medium.com/@ducn/calculate-dynamic-table-view-cell-height-a74516725fcd)

Once you are done with the auto-layout, in your viewdidLoad() method add these two lines of code

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 //just give an estimated size based on your data
tblAmount.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

and you are done. Now the cells will automatically adjust to the content of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your **UIImage** constraint like this.

[image]

trailing , leading , top , bottom and fixed height , width.

also write **UITableViewDelegate** method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: yes this fixes the image issue but the textview is no longer dynamic as in only prints the text on one line rather than multiple lines.

Comment: @husharoonie use UILabel instead of UITextview and set same constrain. only just set numberOfLines=0.

Comment: why cant I use a textView? I need the textView for other purposes such as links... @Dixit Akabari

Comment: I have been at it for days